# svg-pan-zoom disable zooming and draggging for one element

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a map of objects in the svg, so I'm using svg-pan-zoom library to zoom this objects, but i have the single object that shouldn't zooming and dragging, maybe someone has some ideas how to disable this transformation with the single object?

Comment: figure out what the zoom transform is and apply an inverse transform to that object. Or display the shape you don't want to zoom in an entirely different SVG.

Comment: Would be good to understand full context - hence can you share a snippet of working code and what you are trying to achieve? You could have 2 containers (<g>): one "zoomable" and another with no zoom. You could manage elements between these 2 (using dom manipulation if its OK) containers. Actual zoom could be done via transform in this case.